# IDE recommendations for C on Windows

Tags: c, ide, development-environment

Anyone have recommendations for a good C editor for Windows? Any improvement over the Emacs over ssh setup I have right now would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you mentioned C and not C++, I'm going to warn you about Microsoft Visual Studio: its support for C is somewhat poor (C99 support especially).

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951516/what-good-ides-are-availble-for-c

Comment: Technically not a dupe since this question is specifically about windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Visual C++](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) is a great IDE.

If you want something minimalistic, Notepad++ will give you syntax highlighting but stay out of your way.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual C++ (the [Express editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP) are free and very usable) is one of the best IDEs out there, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I should start by pointing out that virtually *any* question about editor preferences pretty much qualifies to be closed as being subjective and argumentative. I don't believe for a moment that you're *trying* to be argumentative, but programmers do get attached to their editors...

If you like Emacs, and it's only the ssh connection that bothers you, then you can get various ports of emacs to Windows.

If you prefer vi and company, you can get vim for Windows.

If you like the normal Windows conventions for editors, Microsoft does a pretty lousy job of imitating it in the latest versions of Visual Studio (lousy compared to older versions at any rate). As compensation for its poor editing, it does have a really nice debugger though.

Another that works quite nicely is Zeus. It's purely an editor, not an IDE (e.g., no built in debugger) but it works well and provides keyboard emulation for everything from Emacs to Wordstar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a nice text editor, [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) is a very good one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a straight text editor that's super powerful, I would give [e](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) a shot. It's based on the well-loved [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) for OS X, and on top of really intelligent sytax highlighting/indenting/whatnot, it's got a pretty powerful suite of macros.

Answer (score 0):

[Source Insight](http://www.sourceinsight.com) is fantastic for showing you code path execution. The color coding is a nice touch and font types and sizes change as well. Many engineers I worked with swore by it.